How can I append some string to InAppWebView?
We have the option to add User-Agent to InAppWebView, but it overrides the User-Agent value.
How can I append some string to the current User-Agent?
final userAgentSuffix = '...';
final userAgent = '$currentUserAgent $userAgentSuffix'; 

InAppWebView(
  initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(
    userAgent: userAgent,
    cacheEnabled: widget.preload,
    useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
  ),
  ...
);

